# Getting error importing ovpn file on raspbian buster using nmcli

Tags: raspbian-buster, networkmanager

I am getting error trying to import ovpn file of open vpn server generated on another raspberry pi

```
root@DietPi:~# nmcli connection import type openvpn  file ./home.ovpn
```

Error: failed to load VPN plugin: unknown VPN plugin "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn".

I do not understand why I am getting this error on my raspberry pi !

Comment: Network manager isn't supported by Raspbian. There are less know how about this custom setup on this site so I'm afraid you are alone with your problem. If you find the solution it would be nice if you share it with the community. Have you considered to use default **dhcpcd** for networking?

Comment: Seems you solved the problem because you already asked a follow up question [how can openvpn to autoconnect and not ask password for connecting to and ovpn profile](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/106047/79866). Please make an answer here how do you solved it and accept it after two days. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again after months.

Comment: Not exactly but i think network manager is supported on latest build of raspbian, i just made progress interms of using openvpn commandline to which we can pass profile file which worked, but i get prompted with password even for an ovpn file.  Second problem is the pi is at remote location and i am taking help of someone to make it work